# make mistakes to push large file to git

Tags: git, push

I have a question:
I made a mistake to push a large file to git, and then I git rm it, however, the git repository has contained this large file, if someone else want to git pull or git clone it, he has to download this large but useless file.
How to solve this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Once you used `git rm` did you then `git commit -m "removed useless file"` and `git push` that commit?

Comment: @user1135469: rest assured, `git rm` will never delete big binary file from git object store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have force push permission to *really* undo your last commit:

This kills last commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

And this pushes it to server:

```
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: it displays  ! [remote rejected] XXX (non-fast forward)

Comment: like I said, you **must** have force push permission to actually do it. Ask server admin to permit that. Otherwise, your big file will be kept in git object store forever (unless you rewind this branch).

Comment: Good answer and comment followup mvp.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could either rewrite the commit history to remove the offending commit altogether, or you can move one commit back and force push your local branch, thereby overriding the history of the remote branch altogether.

Force pushing your local changes is probably the easiest way, if noone else has committed anything in the meantime. Check here on how to perform the process:

https://superuser.com/questions/35267/how-can-i-roll-back-1-commit

There are extensive instructions on how to rewrite the commit history in the git handbook, if you prefer this solution:

http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html